# Calculate average number of visits in last week per id without looping

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with id, date, and number of visits. How to calculate average number of visits in past 7 days (from a given date) per id without looping over every observation in dataframe? The panel is unbalanced, i.e. some dates are missing, so we are not always avaraging over 7.

```
   id        date  visit  avg_past_week
0   1  11/03/2017     10            0.0
1   1  11/12/2017     11            0.0
2   1  11/14/2017     12           11.0
3   1  11/15/2017      8           11.5
```

I need to calculate the last column. Plus, there are many different id's.

Answer (score 2):

Create two new columns that extract week and year -

```
df['week'] = df.date.dt.week
df['year'] = df.date.dt.year
```

And perform a `groupby` on week and year and extract the mean -

```
df_weekavg = df.groupby(['week', 'year']).mean().reset_index()
```

If you want the weekly average data on your original dataframe you will need to do a merge on `week` and `year` (since `df_weekavg` will have the same or fewer rows as `df`).

Comment: Good point, but not exactly what I wanted. My fault, I was not specific enough. I actually want an average over past 7 days. I will edit the initial post.

Comment: So you want an average for the prior 7 days for each line in the dataframe?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC
We using `resample` and `rolling`

```
df['New']=df.date.map(df.set_index('date').iloc[1:].resample('D').sum().rolling(7,min_periods =1).visit.mean()).shift()
df
Out[1460]: 
   id       date  visit  avg_past_week   New
0   1 2017-11-03     10            0.0   NaN
1   1 2017-11-12     11            0.0   NaN
2   1 2017-11-14     12           11.0  11.0
3   1 2017-11-15      8           11.5  11.5
```

adding  `fillna(0)` will give back your expected result

For more id

```
A=[]
for _,df1 in df.groupby('id'):
    A.append( df1.date.map( df1.set_index('date').iloc[1:].resample('D').sum().rolling(7, min_periods=1).visit.mean()).shift())


df['New']=pd.concat(A)
```

Comment: Thanks, Wen. I'm not sure I understand what exactly it does (should spend some time reading), but it seems to work for this example. Though, how do I accommodate multiple id's for the same date? Say, I have additional row with {'id': 2, 'date': '11/14/2017', 'visit':13}. This code sums over visitors for the same day of different id's and then takes average over days, but I need average conditional on id. I hope it makes sense...

Comment: @Daria  then we add `groupby`

Comment: I see, so we still have to loop over id's . Thank you!

Comment: when i do the same way, i always get the error "Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index' ". How do i overcome this?